# Synchronise with google calenar API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm using [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet?fbclid=IwAR1R7mnM9UAfhS-ak7WAhrkFKh8Qg69Lyej5eGS8SP62MRhN8sYGGFmlm_U) and it is working in the console by showing upcoming events while in the browser i have this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1nO6.png)
Any help and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the local Database, is this in the backend, so put the googleCalendar-API in the backend.
But I dont know how the user can allowed your app to access to ther google-calendar. So in this case it would be better to put it in the frontend.

Comment: thnaks now i tried a solution but i'm stuck with 502.5 error

Comment: Please post you code here, so that we can check it and help you.

Comment: well the problem that i'm not sure with how to do it so I just need help in the steps to follow not in the coding so i can synchronize my calendar with google calendar  Thanks

Comment: We can't help you, without code. Post the snippet of the code, so we can try to support you.

Comment: Sorry but it was too long to be put in a snippet .I'm working with this https://github.com/gsuitedevs/browser-samples/blob/master/calendar/quickstart/index.html  I just need hints or steps to follow so i can synchronise my website calendar with angular and .net core and thanks